# Is it safe to delete a lost+found folder?

Tags: filesystem, directory, delete

I have an empty seperate partition used for my vhd/virtualbox. mounted at `/mount/win7`.

I've deleted everything now and there's a lost+found folder left over. It takes up about 5gigs

Is it safe to remove a lost and found folder?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

fsck will recreate the lost+found directory if it is missing.

On startup most distributions run fsck if the filesystem is detected as not being unmounted cleanly.

As fsck creates the lost+found directory if it is missing, it will create it then and place anything that it finds into that directory.

So you can remove it but not recommended (as per Marcelo comment).

Comment: According to this answer in serverfault ( https://serverfault.com/a/9909/486260 ), it is not a good idea to delete it, since in the case of filesystem issues, when fsck recreates the directory during check it could potentially overwrite otherwise salvageable data as it would have no alternative to tie orphaned inodes to directory entries.  The pre-created lost+found directory reserves directory entries for salvaged files during filesystem check

Answer (score 20):

So far I was under the impression that deleting `lost+found` was perfectly safe, as it would be recreated by fsck whenever it is needed. But after the Ubuntu 12.10 upgrade I got this mail from cron:

```
/etc/cron.daily/standard:

Some local file systems lack a lost+found directory. This means if the
file system is damaged and needs to be repaired, fsck will not have
anywhere to put stray files for recovery. You should consider creating
a lost+found directory with mklost+found(8).

The following lost+found directories were not available:

/home/lost+found
```

The man-page of `mklost+found` says:

```
mklost+found pre-allocates disk blocks to the lost+found directory
so that when e2fsck(8) is being run to recover a filesystem, it does 
not  need to allocate blocks in the filesystem to store a large number
of unlinked files.  This ensures that e2fsck will not have to allocate
data blocks in the filesystem during recovery.
```

I am not sure what exactly that means, but it seems to indicate that not having `lost+found` might cause trouble on recovery. Furthermore it indicates that `lost+found` different from a regular directory in that it has preallocated blocks associated with it.

Comment: I believe that the pre-allocation of disk blocks for `lost+found` directory is used to make sure that further allocations will not be needed to be done while the filesystem is in unstable state (during `fsck`). If the file system is already messed up, it might get worse if `fsck` tried to allocate directory entries while restoring lost files. At least `ext2/ext3/ext4` family tries very hard to not make things worse during `fsck` even if the filesystem is totally broken.

Answer (score 3):

You don't want to delete the lost+found directory.
It is an important system folder and will be recreated on next boot anyway. There is some pretty good explanation of why it is there and what it does [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18154/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-lostfound-folder-in-linux-and-unix)