# How to grant permission for newly created partition?

Tags: 13.04, permissions, gparted

[image]

[image]

[image]

I just created 2 brand new partitions (sda6, sda7) from unallocated space. I wish to perform normal operations such as saving files, creating directory, copying files to these 2 brand new partitions but I **cannot** do any of them.

I tried to launch the terminal and using `sudo` command, it seems like I have to grant permission to my login user (kongthap)

1. Please guide me what steps I have to go though?
2. How to label the 2 brand new created partitions to something else readable? (Picture 1)
3. If I didn't want to see Windows partitions (the 2 105GB volumes) while using Ubuntu at all, is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these commands in terminal:

```
sudo chown -R kongthap:kongthap /media/kongthap/9b7ac413-1ddf-4c2e-a74d-75651d6bd37c
sudo chown -R kongthap:kongthap /media/kongthap/37f01625-218e-4027-ac8f-42b135251af5
```

These commands will change the owner of those directories recursively.

To rename them, go in GParted, unmount them and after choose a label name (by right click).

Regarding the third question, see [How to hide a(n) (NTFS) partition from ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124094/how-to-hide-an-ntfs-partition-from-ubuntu).

Comment: What should I do with **lost+found** folder inside each partition?

Comment: I tried `sudo mv /media/kongthap/9b7ac413-1ddf-4c2e-a74d-75651d6bd37c /media/kongthap/sda6` but I got error 
_mv: cannot move ‘/media/kongthap/9b7ac413-1ddf-4c2e-a74d-75651d6bd37c’ to ‘/media/kongthap/sda6’: Device or resource busy_

Comment: @Kongthap Whatever you want. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/165614/is-it-safe-to-delete-a-lostfound-folder . Now, if you have many questions, you should use [Ask Question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) button. Please avoid to ask more then one question once per post.

Comment: @Kongthap Yes, you can't rename them like this. You can do this from GParted, see my new edits.