# A `/home' directory is creatred in my `/media'?

Tags: directory, home-directory

I downloaded a picture with Tor Browser and when the box appeared, I chose Desktop in order to save it there. But the picture was not on my Desktop. After searching for it, I found that there was  another Desktop in my `/media`. And by doing:

```
me@me-K52JT:/$ sudo find -type d -name "Desktop"
```

I got :

```
./root/Desktop
./home/me/Desktop
./home/me/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/Desktop
find: ‘./run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
./media/me/5f2867ae-9b0a-428b-b960-a5e30020e0df/m/Desktop
./media/me/5f2867ae-9b0a-428b-b960-a5e30020e0df/m/snap/movie-monad/8/Desktop
./media/me/5f2867ae-9b0a-428b-b960-a5e30020e0df/m/snap/movie-monad/5/Desktop
./media/me/5f2867ae-9b0a-428b-b960-a5e30020e0df/m/snap/movie-monad/7/Desktop
./media/me/5f2867ae-9b0a-428b-b960-a5e30020e0df/m/tor-browser_de/Browser/Desktop
```

**5f2867ae-9b0a-428b-b960-a5e30020e0df** is a directory in my /media in which there is a home directory of my previous Ubuntu(before reinstall );

```
me@me-K52JT:/home$ ls 
b  me
```

In my previous install I had two users a & m. Now

`/media/me/5f2867ae-9b0a-428b-b960-a5e30020e0df$ ls`
gives:

```
a  lost+found  m
```

I want to know:

- What is that strange directory in my `/media` and why is it created?
- Can I delete it without problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it safe to delete a lost+found folder?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/165614/is-it-safe-to-delete-a-lostfound-folder)

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen Hi George :) He is actually asking about the directory at `/media` which is `5f2867ae-...`.

Comment: ok, taught otherwise!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your old installation of Ubuntu is still living on a partition and somehow it has been mounted, maybe you have clicked on that partition in your file manager.

`/media` is where partitions and removable devices will be mounted on automatically.

From `man hier`:

> /media This directory contains mount points for removable media such as CD and DVD disks or USB sticks.  On systems where more  than  one  device  exists  for mounting a certain type of media.

If you delete `/media` or any sub-directory from there, it means everything that is living on that partition which has been mounted on `/media` will be lost.

And `5f2867ae-9b0a-428b-b960-a5e30020e0df` is the UUID of your partition, you can also find it by running: `sudo blkid` or `lsblk -o name,uuid`.

If your partition had a label for example `myPartition` it would be mounted at:

```
/media/myPartition
```

When partition does not have any label it would be mounted using its UUID:

```
/media/049-349343
```

Comment: Interesting! But why does the image go there instead of my current desktop?

Comment: I believe that image is not there, it should be at `./home/me/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/Desktop`. It's another question about how tor works. It doesn't save the image at your real desktop because of security concerns,

Comment: No it's exactly there & not in ~/tor-browser-_en-US/Browser/Desktop